# Laravel Carousel dynamic with carousel category array

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic, slider, carousel

MY SLIDER OF CATEGORY TEST IS DISPLAYED THIS WAY IN THE PICTURE i.e images appear below each other
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lzpno.jpg)...I have tried change the category test with another category but i could not fix it.. i guess the issue mighty be how to display the active image slide first then the rest come after-wards

**My view blade is**

```xml
@foreach ($data['testSlider'] as $slide )
  <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="carousel-1">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="w-100 d-block" id="imgslide" src= "{{asset('images/' . $slide->image)}}" alt="Slide Image">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-1" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-1" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

**MY SLIDER CONTROLLER HAS**

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\website\backend\Slider;
use App\Models\website\backend\SliderCategory;

public function test()
{
    $data['slider'] = Slider::all();
    $data['slidercategory'] = SliderCategory::all();
    $data['testSlider'] = Slider::with([
        'SliderCategory' => function ($attachmentQuery) {
            $attachmentQuery->where('title', 'test Slider');
        }
    ])->get();

    return view('testboot', compact('data'));
}
```

Comment: You're wrapping the entire carousel html with that foreach instead of only the relevant parts.

Answer (score 0):

Your images are repeating because you are making an entire carousel for each image instead of adding the images to the first carousel.

```ml
<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="carousel-1">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    @foreach ($data['testSlider'] as $slide )
      <div class="carousel-item {{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}">
        <img class="w-100 d-block" id="imgslide-{{$loop->index}}" src= "{{asset('images/' . $slide->image)}}" alt="Slide Image">
      </div>
    @endforeach
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-1" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-1" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    @foreach ($data['testSlider'] as $slide )
      <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="{{ $loop->index }}" class="{{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}"></li>
    @endforeach
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked bro but the image doest slide to the next..Sticks on one image